# Where can I buy lockpicks?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Apart from the occasional 6-10 picks as random loot, I seem to occasionally be running pretty low on lockpicks.

Where can I buy them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Corner Shop in Gorhart, Rikka Egest, is the first person that you encounter who sells lockpicks. It's under the misc section of her shop inventory:

[image]